# Can I make iOS Simulator listen to keyboard events for debugging purposes?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, ios-simulator, keyboard-shortcuts

What I want to do is make some shortcut key for debugging on iOS simulator. e.g. Right Arrow key to call my speed up function to make game run faster. Note that the soft keyboard is not on when I hit debug keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only straightforward way of achieving this (that I can think of) is to create a few very small buttons in your app and connect them to the functions you want to call. You can place them somewhere where they don't interfere with the user interface. Because your developing for a mobile device you unfortunately can't press a key on the keyboard and have it call a function.

Comment: thanks for the answer, @JoJoe. I was hoping to have a workaround since it is actually running on a Simulator. I'll wait a bit more in case somebody has another suggestion. Otherwise, mark your answer as correct. I know that I can use buttons. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Override the `keyCommands` property to enable shortcut keys. It is a property on `UIResponder`, so this can be done in any of your views, view controllers, or even your app delegate.

Answer (score 1):

[FLEX](https://github.com/FLEXTool/FLEX) does all the tricks for you.
You just need to register keys that you are interested in,

```objectivec
FLEXManager *flex = FLEXManager.sharedManager;

// open or close debug
[flex registerSimulatorShortcutWithKey:@"D" modifiers:(UIKeyModifierFlags)0 action:^{
    // Do what you want to do when user click "D" on hardware keyboard
} description:@"Open/Close DebugViewController"];
```